# How to style a text field so it doesnt have a border?

Tags: html, css

I have a text field and I dont want to show border around it as it is a read-only text field.   How can I make it to appear without the border and without the background color?

Comment: could you add some markup-code? any of your css-trials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since you did not give any information about the css version, here's an example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    input[type=text]
    {
        border: 0px;
        background: transparent;
    }
</style>
<input type="text" value="helllo" />
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UMYmL/)

Answer (score 2):

```
#input { border:0; background:transparent; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#your_text_field {
  border-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

**Edit:** Oh well, what do you know, `transparent` actually works on IE6. I remember it not working for certain attributes, such as `border`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   input.asLabel
   {
      border: none;
      background: transparent;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input class="asLabel" type="text" value="See, don't touch :)" disabled/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried something along the lines of:

```
<input class="noBorderAndBackground" type="text" />

noBorderAndBackground{
   background-color:white;
   border-style:none;
}
```